# How to move a picturebox following an ellipse

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

Let's say that i have this Ellipse:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 100, 200, 500, 200);
```

How do I move pictureBox1 following exactly the Ellipse's lines ?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - In addition to the general advice to never use control.CreateGraphics the winforms  answer is: Do the math, there is no 'followPath' function here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GraphicsPath` instead and let the `pictureBox` follow the path of the ellipse:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

//

GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(100, 200, 500, 200));

foreach (PointF point in path.PathPoints)
{
    pictureBox1.Location = Point.Round(point);
    Thread.Sleep(100); // just for the demonstration
}
```

Comment: It kinda worked,but it throws the error : 'The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context' Do you know what can I do?

Comment: add `using System.Threading;` to the top of your class. But since I just inserted it for demonstration you should remove it and fit the code for your purpose.